# Pycharm: Changes made have no effect, how to explain this behaviour?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm

This problem only happens in Pycharm:

I made a very simple NN based on TF2.0 website tutorial. The weird thing about it is when I change batch_size, it keeps going with the old one as if I did nothing. In fact, everything I do is irrelevant.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255


class Prototype(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Prototype, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')
        self.l2 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')
        self.l3 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')
    def call(self, ip):
        x = self.l1(ip)
        x = self.l2(x)
        return self.l3(x)

model = Prototype()
model.build(input_shape=(None, 784,))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
```

> ```
> batch_size = 250
> train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size)
> ```

```
def train_one_epoch():
  for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
    print(x_batch_train.shape)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      logits = model(x_batch_train)  # Logits for this minibatch
      loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

I run the train_one_epoch(), it trains for one epoch. Then I change batch size and consequently dataset object to give new chunk sizes, **BUT** when I run train_one_epoch() again, it keeps going with the old batch_size.

Proof:
[image]

Comment: PS: If my training loop wasn't wrapped in a function, this problem doesn't happen. Additionally, I've just found that if I redefine that function train_one_epoch() the changes take effect. But why is it like this?

Comment: Did you explicitly change the dataset, or did you just expect the dataset to change because the batch size changed?

Comment: No, I didn't change the dataset. But I changed the batch_size, so that dataset object will give chunks of the new size when iterated over.

Comment: If you just change the variable named "`batch_size`", there is no reason the `train_dataset` object should change. It only sees the value of the batch size when the `batch` function is called.

Comment: But I reran the line that comes after it. That's why I put both of them in one block to highlight that.

Comment: Hmm... When I tried this (changing `batch_size` to 100 and rerunning the following line), the results seem right (the program outputs `(100, 784)` instead of `(250, 784)`). Maybe you forgot to mention something else?

Comment: Thanks for trying it. When you say rerunning, do you mean restarting the entire code? What I meant, is keeping the console opened, changing the batch_size and getting new dataset object, then running the train_one_epoch again after the change, not the entire program. Do you see my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194988/discussion-between-imperishable-night-and-alex-deft).